# finding all visible char in txtfile in MATLAB (and checking for no existing file)

Tags: matlab, char, text-files

I'm quite new in MATLAB. I have to write a function that counts the number of a certain character in a text file. 2 input arguments are requested: fname (char vector of the filename) and character (the char it counts in the file).

Output argument: the number of characters found. If the file is not found or character is not a valid char, the function return -1.

I wrote a function which passed correctly two of the 4 tests. The two wrong ones are:

==> 1) Test with all visible characters

Explanation: Variable charnum has an incorrect value. When testing with '#' your solution returned -1 which is incorrect. (0)

==> 2) Non existent file

For number 2), no explanation provided.

This is my code:

```
function charnum = char_counter(fname, character)
A = fileread(fname);
char_1 = strfind(A, character);
charnum = numel(char_1);
if isfile(fname) == 0 %doesn't work... 
    charnum = -1;
elseif exist(fname) == 0
    charnum = -1;
elseif charnum == 0
    charnum = -1;
elseif ischar(character) == 0
    charnum = -1;
fclose(fid);
end
```

Thank you all for your suggestions and advice.

I understand, for the 1) that I probably should add an instruction to take into account all the characters but I can't find a satisfying way that works. Because when I test for the character '#', it works correctly on my MATLAB: 
When I test the function with the visible character '#' the answer is correct.

For 2) I don't understand why my 4th line doesn't work correctly. 
I already check various options found on the Internet but so far it did not fix the problem.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your questions:

1) `A = fileread(fname)` will throw an error before you can get to the if statements, so you will have to restructure your code to take that into account.

However, you can use the `isequal` function to compare two things for an if statement. [`isfile`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/isfile.html) returns a 0 if the file is not found, so you can compare that to 0.

```
if isequal(isfile(fname),0)
    charnum = -1;
```

2) The function [`ischar`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ischar.html) returns 0 if the input is not a character array. ***This will return 0 for string arrays***, so make 100% sure your input is a character array. Use [`char`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/char.html) to do this:

```
elseif isequal(ischar(char(character)),0)
    charnum = -1;
```

Here is what your function could look like:

```
function charnum = char_counter(fname, character)
    if isequal(isfile(fname),0)
        charnum = -1;
    else    
        A = fileread(fname);
        char_1 = strfind(A, character);
        charnum = numel(char_1);
        if isequal(exist(fname),0)
            charnum = -1;
        elseif isequal(charnum,0)
            charnum = -1;
        elseif isequal(ischar(char(character)),0)
            charnum = -1;
        end
        fclose(fid);
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you very much, @medicine_man! Your explanations are very clear: it helps me a lot to better understand how the isequal functions. I check the solution with the suggestions: it works for non existent files but I still have an error for the characters. With the same explanation (Variable charnum has an incorrect value. When testing with '#' your solution returned -1 which is incorrect.). I really have trouble to understand why it still poses problem.

Comment: You want to test letters and numbers?

Comment: What would a sample input file look like? Add it to your original question.

Comment: I created a text file, put only the character `#` in it, and ran it myself. `charnum` returned with a value of 1.

Comment: Regarding your questions, the exercise only mentions: "The function returns charnum, the number of characters found. If the file is not found or character is not a valid char, the function return -1.". My question is how we specify what a valid char is? The symbol "#" isn't? I thought it was. Same for letters and numbers.

Comment: `#` is a valid ASCII character. Like I mentioned earlier, I created a test file with only the char `#` in it, and the function I answered with returned `1` for me.

Comment: I understand that # is a valid ASCII character but when I tried it with the new version of the code, MathWorks learning Tool mentions another problem : "Variable charnum has an incorrect value. char_counter('simple.txt',11) failed...". 11 isn't a valid ASCII character? Thank you very much for your time, I really appreciate it.

Comment: `1` is, but `11` reads as two 1's in succession. Another issue may be that you are trying to load in a number (integer, double, or float) instead of a character. [`strfind`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strfind.html) takes inputs of strings. Try converting all your inputs to strings, (especially `character`).

Comment: You'll probably need a check at the start of the function that checks whether or not the `character` variable is a character or a double.

Comment: Indeed, that is what I tried to do a moment ago. Right after A = fileread(...) I add: characters = char(character);
char_1 = strfind(A, characters);
charnum = numel(char_1);    When I tested it into the Learning Tool, problem was 'Variable charnum has an incorrect value. When testing with '#' your solution returned -1 which is incorrect. (0)' which is weird because on my MATLAB, it works fine! When I test it with '#' it gives me 4, the correct number of # in my file.txt.

Comment: Which Learning Toolbox are you trying to use?

Comment: I send my exercises on a tool named "https://learningtool.mathworks.com/launch" that I have to use for the MOOC on MATLAB I'm attending (Introduction to Programming with MATLAB). At home, I have a regular version of MATLAB R2018b.

Comment: I finally solved the problem! Simply by adding a condition: 
    elseif isequal(ischar(character),0)
        charnum = -1;
And it worked perfectly! Thank you again for your help @medicine_man!